# FB.ui stream.publish - Formatting the description parameter

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook application that I've now put live, but I need to make an amendment, but I can't find anything to suggest that it's possible or not.  I am basically looking at formatting the description to include line breaks e.g.

```
description: (
    'Hey look at my StackOverflow question\r\n' + 
    'Great isn\'t it?'
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<br />` ?

no idea, that might work... if not, character encode the linebreaks.

Comment: Unfortunately not :o(  My hatred for Facebook grows.

Comment: "Is this possible?" - Evidently not

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but,

If you could use php, this use : nl2br() function
Example:

```
nl2br($FBeventDescription)
```

You can also have a look at this link: [PHPjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480)